# retreive url for current user's profile

Tags: apex

A Hierarchy Custom Setting stores a specific URL for each profile in Salesforce.
How to retrieve the correct URL for the current user's profie and display this on a Visualforce Page?

Comment: Anzar--- any reason this issue still open ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use** `{!$Setup.ratan__Test__c.ratan__url__c}` in VF page.

It will fetch the record based on current user's profile/ userid.

**Note:** - `ratan__Test__c` is Custom setting API name and `ratan__url__c` is field name

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand the answers above

If you use the `getInstance()` method, you will automatically get the override for the current user: the user's settings, or the profile settings if the former is null, or the org defaults if the former 2 are null. Even if there are no org defaults, you will get a blank settings object.

The syntax, using Apex, is:

```
CustomSetting__c.getInstance().UrlField__c;
```

@Ratan has posted a good way of showing them in VF with just markup and no code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hierarchy custom setting method to get the corresponding url.

```
Customsettingname__c.getInstance(Userinfo.getProfileId()).UrlField__c;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom setting and access it using some of the methods provided, you are retrieving your data with zero impact on the governor limits. You aren't using any of your limited SOQL queries or counting towards the limited number of query rows you can retrieve.

```
Custom_Page__c cp = Custom_Page__c.getOrgDefaults();
string url = cp.url__c;
```

This returns you the org defaults for that custom setting, or the highest level.

You can also pass in the userID or the profileID if you have different settings based on profiles or individual users:

```
Custom_Page__c cp = Custom_Page__c.getOrgDefaults(<UserID or ProfileID>);
string url = cp.url__c;
```